# Jquery when form is clicked hide other forms on the page

Tags: jquery

hello i have managed to fade inactive forms when the user is clicking within another form. each form has a class of palletbuilder. i would now like to hide the buttons within the other form to. the buttons have a class named addBUtton the code so far

```
$(".palletbuilder").click(function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.siblings().animate({
     opacity: 0.5
        }, 500);

    $t.animate({
    opacity: 1
        }, 500);
});
```

Comment: can you show the form html? Are the "other" buttons within the working form or the faded form?

Comment: Inactive forms, or inactive form elements (`input`s, `select`s, `button`s and so on)..?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(".palletbuilder").click(function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.siblings().animate({
     opacity: 0.5
        }, 500);

    $t.animate({
    opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    $(".addBUtton").each(function () {
      $(this).hide();
    )};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you may be looking for:

```
$t.children('.addBUtton').show();
$t.siblings().children('.addBUtton').hide();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cdkAP/

Answer (score 0):

```
$t.siblings().find(':input.addButton').hide()
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xN5aV/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'not' operator provided by jQuery to exclude objects.

```
$(function() {
  $("form").hover(function(){
    $("form button").not($(this).find('button')).fadeTo(400, 0.5);
  }, function(){
$("form button").fadeTo(0, 1);  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".palletbuilder").click(function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.siblings().animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 500).children('button.addBUtton, input:button.addBUtton').hide();
    $t.animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500).children().show();//show them again if click that form???
});
```

I did not know if you used input or button markup so I accounted for both. (or you could just use the class)

Edit: (just because) combine it all:

```
$(".palletbuilder").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500).children().show().end().siblings().animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 500).children('button.BUtton, input.BUtton').hide();
});
```